# Why do I receive a global variable not defined error?

Tags: python

Here's a fragment of my code:

```
class myClass:
    verbs {'hear': 3, 'do': 5}

    def __init__(self):
        self.D = self.create_dictionary()

    def create_dictionary(self):
        D = {}
        for entry in verbs:
            D[verbs[entry]] = {}
```

I get a runtime error at loop line: "global name 'verbs' is not defined". I haven't been able to figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing the assignment `=` in `verbs = {'hear': 3, 'do': 5}`.

Second, `verbs` isn't completely global, it lives inside `myClass`. To reference it, use `myClass.verbs` or assign it outside the class, which I think matches more your intention, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
class myClass:

    verbs={'hear': 3, 'do': 5}

    def __init__(self):
        self.D = self.create_dictionary()

    def create_dictionary(self):
        D = {}
        for entry in self.verbs:
            D[self.verbs[entry]] = {}
```

or better to include verbs definition inside constructor.